# FFTW and fft with MatLab

Tags: matlab, fft, fftw

I have a weird problem with the discrete fft. I know that the Fourier Transform of a Gauss function exp(-x^2/2) is again the same Gauss function exp(-k^2/2). I tried to test that with some simple code in MatLab and FFTW but I get strange results.

First, the imaginary part of the result is not zero (in MatLab) as it should be.

Second, the absolute value of the real part is a Gauss curve but without the absolute value half of the modes have a negative coefficient. More precisely, every second mode has a coefficient that is the negative of that what it should be.

Third, the peak of the resulting Gauss curve (after taking the absolute value of the real part) is not at one but much higher. Its height is proportional to the number of points on the x-axis. However, the proportionality factor is not 1 but nearly 1/20.

Could anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the MatLab code that I used:

```
    function [nooutput,M] = fourier_test

    Nx = 512;      % number of points in x direction

    Lx = 50;        % width of the window containing the Gauss curve

    x = linspace(-Lx/2,Lx/2,Nx);     % creating an equidistant grid on the x-axis

    input_1d = exp(-x.^2/2);                 % Gauss function as an input
    input_1d_hat = fft(input_1d);            % computing the discrete FFT
    input_1d_hat = fftshift(input_1d_hat);   % ordering the modes such that the peak is centred

    plot(real(input_1d_hat), '-')
    hold on
    plot(imag(input_1d_hat), 'r-')
```

Comment: You may be mixing up the *continuous* FT with the *discrete* FT. The continuous FT of a gaussian is a gaussian, but I'm not sure that's true for a DFT (FFT).

Comment: Of course, discreteness make things imprecise but the discrete FT is created as an approximation of the continuous FT. When the number of points and the interval are large enough, which is the case here, the approximation should be good. There will be some deviations, but they should definitely not be so large and so systematic. Also, when I increase Nx and Lx, the result does not change which means that convergence is achieved.

Comment: I think also there may be an implicit time shift in your DFT case, which translates to a phase rotation in the frequency domain - I would expect the magnitude to be correct and the phase to be a straight line (modulo 2π if you're not unwrapping it, i.e. a sawtooth).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is basically what Paul R suggests in his second comment, you introduce a phase shift (linearly dependent on the frequency) because the center of the Gaussian described by `input_1d_hat` is effectively at `k>0`, where `k+1` is the index into `input_1d_hat`. Instead if you center your data (such that `input_1d_hat(1)` corresponds to the center) as follows you get a phase-corrected Gaussian in the frequency domain:

```
    Nx = 512;      % number of points in x direction
    Lx = 50;        % width of the window containing the Gauss curve

    x = linspace(-Lx/2,Lx/2,Nx);     % creating an equidistant grid on the x-axis

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    x=fftshift(x);   % <-- center
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    input_1d = exp(-x.^2/2);                 % Gauss function as an input
    input_1d_hat = fft(input_1d);            % computing the discrete FFT
    input_1d_hat = fftshift(input_1d_hat);   % ordering the modes such that the peak is centered

    plot(real(input_1d_hat), '-')
    hold on
    plot(imag(input_1d_hat), 'r-')
```

From the definition of the DFT, if the Gaussian is not centered such that maximum occurs at `k=0`, you will see a phase twist. The effect off `fftshift` is to perform a circular shift or swapping of left and right sides of the dataset, which is equivalent to shifting the center of the peak to `k=0`.

As for the amplitude scaling, that is an issue with the definition of the DFT implemented in Matlab. From the documentation for the FFT:

> ```
> For length N input vector x, the DFT is a length N vector X,
> with elements
>                  N
>    X(k) =       sum  x(n)*exp(-j*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1)/N), 1 <= k <= N.
>                 n=1
> The inverse DFT (computed by IFFT) is given by
>                  N
>    x(n) = (1/N) sum  X(k)*exp( j*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1)/N), 1 <= n <= N.
>                 k=1
> ```

Note that in the forward step the summation is *not* normalized by N. Therefore if you increase the number of points `Nx` in the summation while keeping the width `Lx` of the Gaussian function constant you will increase `X(k)` proportionately.

As for signal leaking into the imaginary frequency dimension, that is due to the discrete form of the DFT, which results in truncation and other effects, as noted again by Paul R. If you reduce `Lx` while keeping `Nx` constant, you should see a reduction in the amount of signal in the imaginary dimension *relative* to the real dimension (compare the spectra while keeping peak intensities in the real dimension equal).

You'll find additional answers to similar questions [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40257-gaussian-fft) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/41380).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. However, I still do not understand why should I change the x-array with fftshift. Could you elaborate on that a little bit? I thought this were provided by doing fftshift on the output. Why is the Gaussian in my version effectively centred at x>0?

Comment: Do you have any idea about the reason for the other two issues that I have? I implemented your solution. It fixes the oscillations in both parts of the output but the imaginary part is still not zero. Moreover, when I change the number of points Nx, it stays the same while the peak of the real part changes proportionally to Nx. Any idea why this is like that?

Comment: Any idea how to fix that issue with FFTW when used with C++? There I get the same nasty oscillations.

Could you give a mathworks-reference about that issue? I didn't see a remark about that on the page where the fft routine is explained.

Comment: @Fortran_user regarding your first question, when I mean center I mean set the value of the "time" domain variable to zero at the center of the peak. To FFT, input_1d(1) is the value of the amplitude at "zero time".

Comment: @Fortran_user The other effect can be explained as a result of the discrete nature of the DFT.